# Setting GCServer = True when running on Linux in .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, garbage-collection

How do set GCServer to true in a .net core project? Usually in .net framework projects I add an App.Config xml file that sets GCServer variable to true but this does not work in a 
.net core project running on Linux (the App.Config file is generated and publish but the variable still doesn't change)

Comment: You can use the property `<ServerGarbageCollection>True</ServerGarbageCollection>` in the csproj. But in dotnetcore it's already true by default

Comment: If that is the case then why does GCSettings.IsServerGC return false?

Comment: Hum it's true in my app. You can check the real value in `/bin/debug/MyProject.runtimeconfig.json`. See this video from asp community standup for more details https://youtu.be/DiqqlDPfch4?list=PL1rZQsJPBU2StolNg0aqvQswETPcYnNKL&t=3519

Comment: I am on Linux as well, and I can see the same issue on mine. `.runtimeconfig.json` does not contain `System.GG.Server`. And `GCSettings.IsServerGC` returns false too.

Comment: @Kalten Looking at the docs and some quick testing locally, it looks like  `<ServerGarbageCollection>` is only `True` for Web projects (`Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`). Otherwise it needs to be set explicitly.

Comment: @omajid just do be clear how exactly do you set it explicitly?

Comment: Like @Kalten said, add `<ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection> ` to your `csproj` file.

Comment: @omajid, thx for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `<ServerGarbageCollection>True</ServerGarbageCollection>` to your csproj file. Like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To confirm that it's being correctly set during build, check your `<PROJECT>.runtimeconfig.json` file in the `bin` directory. It should contain something like:

```
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
```

In some cases, the GCServer is already the default. You can check if there's a default value your msbuild file by using `msbuild /pp`:

```
$ dotnet msbuild /pp | grep -i ServerGarbage
<ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.GC.Server" Condition="'$(ServerGarbageCollection)' != ''" Value="$(ServerGarbageCollection)" />
```

If you have a csproj file with `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`, then it's already the default:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

$ dotnet msbuild /pp | grep -i ServerGarbage
<ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.GC.Server" Condition="'$(ServerGarbageCollection)' != ''" Value="$(ServerGarbageCollection)" />
```

Comment: OK so I tried what you suggested and it seems that it works only for .net core project i.e. I add `<ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>` to the csproj file and it changes the GC but it seems that in .net framework project adding the flag doesn't change anything and the only way to do it is by adding an App.config file

Comment: Hi, may I confirm that if there are some projects the web project (Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web") depended on, should all projects be marked GC mode explicitly or just the web project？